# Dynamic max-width for columns in grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a grid with three columns where the first column should be as wide as possible, except if there is text in the two other columns that could fill the space.

This is my working code:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content max-content;
  gap: 10px;
}

.ellipsis-item {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.item {
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid 1</h2>

<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="item header">Column 1</div>
  <div class="item header">Column 2</div>
  <div class="item header">Column 3</div>
  <div class="item">1 Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="item ellipsis-item">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
  <div class="item ellipsis-item">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
</div>

<h2>Grid 2</h2>

<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="item header">Column 1</div>
  <div class="item header">Column 2</div>
  <div class="item header">Column 3</div>
  <div class="item">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
  <div class="item ellipsis-item">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
  <div class="item ellipsis-item">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
</div>
```

In the case of "Grid 1", I would like the first column to only be as wide as it needs to be. I.e. I want to be able to see more text in column two and three.

In the case of "Grid 2", I would like the last two columns to have a maximum width of, lets say 100 px, or preferably, the width of the text of Column 2 and Column 3, respectively. Then I want the first column to fill the remaining space (basically as it looks now).

EDIT: Grid 1 and 2 are just examples of the same grid, I don't want two different stylings.

Comment: if by "grid2" you mean column 2 items, why do you want them to have a max width of 100px? That's pretty much what your rendered example looks like. I think instead you probably want column 1 width to have a maximum value, and divide up the remaining space with `1fr` for each of cols 2 and 3.

Comment: Grid 2 are a bit further down in the example (you have to scroll, will see if I can make it clearer that there are two examples).

Answer (score 1):

Is this getting close?

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
}

.g1 {
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.g2 {
  grid-template-columns: auto 100px 100px;
}

.ellipsis-item {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid 1</h2>

<div class="grid-wrapper g1">
  <div class="item header">Column 1</div>
  <div class="item header">Column 2</div>
  <div class="item header">Column 3</div>
  <div class="item">1 Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="item ellipsis-item">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
  <div class="item ellipsis-item">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<h2>Grid 2</h2>

<div class="grid-wrapper g2">
  <div class="item header">Column 1</div>
  <div class="item header">Column 2</div>
  <div class="item header">Column 3</div>
  <div class="item">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
  <div class="item ellipsis-item">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
  <div class="item ellipsis-item">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is how I want it to look, but I don't want two different styles for it. Grid 1 and Grid 2 are just two examples of the same grid, if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `max-width: 100px` and used

```
grid-template-columns: auto minmax(100px, 1fr) minmax(100px, 1fr)
```

which is close enough to what I wanted.